# how to concatenate all inputs including whitepaces to one string?

Tags: bash, posix

for a script

```
script.sh < a b                              c a
```

I want to put the inputs in one string, like that

```
string=" a b                              c a"
```

ie, preserve the spaces

how can i do that?

thanks

Comment: Quote them when calling: `script.sh " a b         c a"`.

Comment: Or escape them, but quoting is more reasonable if you have a number of whitespaces.

Comment: that works, any way to do that without the quotes?

Comment: no -- please take a primer on shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [here documents](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) and [here strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t INPUT
printf "input: %s\n" "${INPUT[@]}"
```

example:

```
bash script.sh <<< "a b c"
```

Comment: A simple `IFS= read -r INPUT` would suffice; no need to involve `readarray` (which is non-standard and requires `bash` 4 or later).

Comment: It's a speedy reply in which I decided to not go for a loop which complicates the crucial concept (using here docs/here strings) more a bit.